# What are the rules for the traffic circles on Pleasant Avenue in Maywood NJ

Tags: driving, traffic, roundabouts

Given the "traffic circle" visible [on street view here](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.9064408,-74.0657238,3a,75y,109.82h,69.23t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s29ULVdHGHGyaqb4PncXd_Q!2e0!7i16384!8i8192)

What road rules are applicable? Do I have to give way to the right? or only cars already in the circle?

Comment: NJ traffic circles have been confusing for decades, and still are. See, for example, https://www.jefftk.com/p/nj-still-has-silly-rotary-rules

Comment: Slow down and don't hit anybody. Watch out for pickup trucks and wayward ducks. Keep your eyes open and your mouth closed. It's New Jersey, Jake. Forget about it.

Comment: We have these tiny circles in UK too. We are well accustomed to roundabouts, but on these, when there is other traffic drivers generally slow down or stop, signal, observe, make eye contact and polite gestures etc. and proceed carefully.

Comment: Yeah, New Jersey isn’t like that…

Comment: @JonCuster ok, but if you behave like that when the other driver doesn't, you'll still avoid an accident.  The other driver may think less of you for being such a pushover, but so what?

Comment: Indeed, @phoog, a healthy level of paranoia is good for you in general, doubly so at New Jersey traffic circles.

Comment: This is not a traffic circle.  Pleasant is a through street; the cross streets have stop lines and stop signs.  I would _guess_ that the arrows are just to emphasize pathing for left turns (onto or off of Pleasant) due to Pleasant having two wide lanes separated by the raised garden bed.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Based on the comments above, I still don't have an answer. @user4556274 might be right that it is not a traffic circle, although I'm not 100% convinced. Either way, I'm still not sure how to behave except to exercise extreme caution. At this point I'm inclined to treat it as a "rolling" 4 way intersection without stop signs.